# Undelete files from git repository

Tags: git

I want to revert to my previous commit (commit 4d462937b006da1fbc710bc33bf3bab76de1ede2) with all my files (some of them were deleted)

```
(venv) [ndale@my_arch project]$ git log

commit d0b07921e818c5c5abdb92f0e563f4d186370b6f
Author: Nikos Dalezios <ndalezios@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 1 21:03:11 2016 +0200

    test

commit 4d462937b006da1fbc710bc33bf3bab76de1ede2
Author: Nikos Dalezios <ndalezios@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 28 20:07:01 2016 +0200

    ok



(venv) [ndale@my_arch project]$ git reflog
d0b0792 HEAD@{0}: pull origin master: Fast-forward
4d46293 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 4d46293
e0e0368 HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD^
4d46293 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to 4d46293
d0b0792 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from 4d462937b006da1fbc710bc33bf3bab76de1ede2 to d0b0792
4d46293 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from master to 4d46293
4d46293 HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to HEAD^
d0b0792 HEAD@{7}: commit: test
4d46293 HEAD@{8}: commit: ok
```

I really messed things up, and I lost a few files of python code (a few hundred lines).  HEAD@{8} is the point where I need to go back.....

Thanks

I don't know if this helps but my command history is this

```
git rm -r *
git reset --hard HEAD
git reset HEAD
git commit -a
git reset --hard HEAD^
git checkout 4d46293
git checkout d0b0792
git reset --hard 4d46293
git reset --hard HEAD^ #4d46293
```

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't pushed your commits up to your remote repository yet (Github, Bitbucket, etc..) then you can use

```
git reset --hard 4d462937b006da1fbc710bc33bf3bab76de1ede2
```

This essentially removes any records related to your commit.

If, on the other hand, you have already pushed your commit to a remote repository, then you'll want to do

```
git revert 4d462937b006da1fbc710bc33bf3bab76de1ede2
```

which undo your changes and records this undo in the commit history.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard 4d462937b006da1fbc710bc33bf3bab76de1ede2`